# Codeigniter: Call a function inside another function and replace it's URL with the function called

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have these sample codes:

**Controller**

```
public function one()
{
   $this->two();  
   // url equals localhost/project/index.php?/one
}

public function two()
{
   // some code.. 
   // url still equals localhost/project/index.php?/one
}
```

How will I change the URL to ***localhost/project/index.php?/two*** whenever I call two() under one()?

Comment: use codeigniter route https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

Hope this example will help you out to understanding the routes concept:

**Controller**

```
class Abc extends CI_Model {
 public function one()
 {
 }

 public function two()
 {
 }
}
```

config => **Routes**

```
$route['new-first-url'] = 'abc/one';

$route['new-second-url'] = 'abc/two';
```

**in browser url -**

for method one => https://localhost:80/project_name/new-first-url

for method two => https://localhost:80/project_name/new-second-url